# How can I replace all the " " values with Zero's in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].fillna("S")
```

titanic_df is data frame,Embarked is a column name. I have to missing cells in my column  i.e blank spaces and I want to add "S" at the missing place but the code I mentioned above is not working.Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].replace(" ", "S")
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

titanic_df = pd.DataFrame({'Embarked':['a','d',' ']})
print (titanic_df)
  Embarked
0        a
1        d
2       

titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].replace(" ", "S")

print (titanic_df)
  Embarked
0        a
1        d
2        S
```

---

Also you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex if need replace one or more whitespaces.
 `^` means the beginning of whitespace(s), `$` means the end of  whitespace(s):

```
titanic_df = pd.DataFrame({'Embarked':['a ',' d',' ', '    ']})
print (titanic_df)
  Embarked
0       a 
1        d
2         
3   

titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].str.replace("^\s+$", "S")
#same output
#titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].replace("^\s+$", "S", regex=True)
print (titanic_df)
  Embarked
0       a 
1        d
2        S
3        S
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `apply`

```
titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].apply(lambda x: "S" if x == " " else x)
```